# Responsive video slider in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, android-video-player

Is there any better solution to make video frames fully responsive to the slider when it is dragged?

I'm using below code on slider value changed event, But the frames are not responding as per the slider value.

```
     public void OnProgressBarDownClicked()
    {
        if (videoPlayer.isPaused)
        videoPlayer.time = (float)videoProgressBar.value;
    }
```

Trying to achive Youtube like progess bar.

Comment: Is it working but slow or not working at all?

Comment: it is working fine in editor but in android and ios devices the frames get updated after i stop moving the slider